# Feature request: Math Jax autoNumber:AMS option

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

I'd like to be able to auto-number equations and label them so i can refer to them in the text. Math Jax provides a built-in way to do this by setting the autoNumber option to AMS. I realize that by adding this option to the universal template, existing code will be affected in such a way that some equations will get unduly auto-numbered. Is there any way to allow individual users to specify this option for their posts, either once and for all, or on a per-post level? If not, what is the recommended way to number equations and refer to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\tag{1}\label{mylabel}
$$
and refer to it like $\eqref{mylabel}$

This can also be used in [a normal link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9131/feature-request-math-jax-autonumberams-option#mjx-eqn-mylabel)

**Caveat:** I believe that these labels need to be unique within a question.

Comment: I'd guess the OP also meant the number will be auto generated.

Comment: @Royi: yes, but "If not, what is the recommended way to number equations and refer to them?"

Comment: Is it impossible to get auto numbering in MathJaX?

Comment: @Royi: as far as I know (which doesn't mean "yes"). However, auto-numbering is usually set up before `\begin{document}`  and MathJax seems to be encapsulated inside a `\begin{document}...\end{document}` environment.